# Why is the dual space called like that?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology

While studying linear transformations I came across the term *dual space*.

I do understand what it is, but I don't understand why is it named so. Can somebody explain why it's called dual space?

Comment: It is because of the way, the basis of the dual space is constructed, using the basis from the vector space, from which, the set of all linear transformations to it's field, is the dual space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relationship between a vector space $V$ and its dual space $V^*$ is one of [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)).  A key aspect of duality is that, under certain assumptions of the "niceness" of $V$, $V^{**}$ (the dual space of the dual space) is $V$.